# Customization of tabs in Oracle Apex page

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to customize the tab designs in page. I'm using 4.2 version.

I chosen one level of tabs and I changed the colors and font style. Now I want to change the tab design of my own.

Can anybody solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can completely change the HTML used to render the tabs, which is defined in the page templates here:

[image: APEX page template]

Since APEX tabs are notoriously difficult to use it is also quite common to not use them at all and instead define tabs using List regions for example, which makes them a lot more flexible.